# Capture request/response bandwidth of webapp deployed in Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, web-applications, war, bandwidth

My requirement is to measure the request and response bandwidth of a webapp that's deployed in Tomcat. Basically capture each request and response bandwidth and store the statistics and do analytics on that data overtime.

We've already written a custom Tomcat Valve to capture plenty of information regarding requests coming to a webapp. Since both request and response go through the Valve, I think there should be a way to capture bandwidth stats in the Valve, but haven't found out how to do it.

One thing we've done previously is to get this information using the Tomcat RequestInfo.java class. This however doesn't seem like a clean solution. While digging into the tomcat code, I noticed that we can get the org.apache.coyote.Request object (that's used in RequestInfo class) as follows;

```
org.apache.catalina.connector.request.getCoyoteRequest().getBytesRead(); 
org.apache.catalina.connector.request.getCoyoteRequest().getResponse().getContentWritten();
```

But both the above statement always returns 0, which is wrong compared to the output in RequestInfo class.

Any idea on what could be the issue? Why the coyote.Request is not returning the correct bandwidth in the Valve? Is there a better way to capture request/response bandwidth, with or without a Valve ?!